# Can't access Google Cloud Text To Speech with API Key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to use cloud text to speech to add accessibility to a web-based game. It is being built in Unity for WebGL.

Eventually I am firing a web request towards the following URL: `string url = "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=" + apiKey;`, including the proper API key.

However I always receive 403 Forbidden errors when trying to synthesize text:

```
webgl.framework.js.gz:3 [Google TTS] Received response FORBIDDEN from Google. Please check whether your API key restrictions might be blocking this call. You might have set this to only be allowed from your website. If so, you might want to create an unrestricted Editor-only API key which you're using for development.

webgl.framework.js.gz:3 [Google TTS] Error Code: 403 - HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

POST https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=<key redacted> 403 (Forbidden)
```

The key seems to be configured correctly, as seen below:

API Key configuration; restricted to certain websites and TTS API:

[image: API Key configuration; restricted to certain websites and TTS API]

It is set to restrict to the website (I triple checked the URLs, they are matching and it doesn't work without http referrer restrictions either) and restricted to Cloud Text To Speech API.

The API is enabled as well and I can see the requests come through but they always throw an error:

Enabled API, 100% error rate:

[image: Enabled API, 100% error rate]

There also is a valid and configured billing account assigned to the project.

I saw various tutorials doing the same but I can not get it to work... Do API keys no longer function for cloud TTS?

Comment: Not an answer, but I do not recommend using API Keys. For many services they are being dropped in newer API versions - use a service account instead.

Comment: If the API key in your post is valid, please delete it in the Google Cloud Console GUI. If you are posting dummy keys, please tell us in your post.

Comment: Edit your quest to include the entire HTTP request (mask secrets).

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for the edit suggestion. It was an already restricted key though, so it shouldnt be able to be used anywhere other than on the target website. Useful pointer though, I just missed it in the setup...

Thanks for the pointer towards service accounts, I will change it in a future release but this needed to get out quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud to Speech still supports API key (OAuth is another option). Your issue is likely related to Google API key application restriction configuration, when the request is sent from WebGL in Unity. You can validate your API key by running a direct curl command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @request.json https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=[your-api-key]
```

request.json can be a simple request body object:

```
{
    "input": {
        "text": "Hello Google Speech to Text."
    },
    "voice": {
        "languageCode": "en-US",
        "name": "en-US-Standard-A",
        "ssmlGender": "FEMALE"
    },
    "audioConfig": {
        "audioEncoding": "MP3"
    }
}
```

You may need to temporarily change your API key application restriction to none or use the IP address of your test machine. This will tell whether your API key works or not.

If that works, you might want to dig a bit more into how WebGL sends REST request. For example, does it alter the website domain name or sub-domain names. If so, it will cause the Google API throwing 403 Forbidden error. (Disclaimer: I am no WebGL SME)

Comment: Thanks @Gang Chen this was quite helpful. Through the curl command I figured that my original key seemingly had some issues and created a new one, which then worked.

In addition, I changed my domain restriction from www.myDomain.com/* to \*.myDomain.com/\* to fit the subdomain (qa.myDomain.com).... So thats something to watch out for too :)